# Selenium - screenshot with different names

Tags: python

I'm using Selenium to grab a screenshot from a list of urls. test.txt include reddit.com, stackoverflow.com and spotify.com. When iterating through this list I want it to save in the folder Screenshots with the file name being the url + '.png'. It does not work though. I'm either getting errors or it just keeps running without doing anything.
This one works but it just overwrites the old one

```
screenshot = driver.save_screenshot('Screenshots/foo.png')
```

I want it to look like this but it does not work:

```
screenshot = driver.save_screenshot('Screenshots/', line,  '.png')
```

I am new to python but it doesn't work using + instead ' either.
The problem is that it takes too many arguments.

```
class Screenshot():

filehandle = open("test.txt", "r")
for line in filehandle:
    DRIVER = 'chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER)
    driver.get(line)

    screenshot = driver.save_screenshot('Screenshots/foo.png')
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: If you do `print(line)` in your loop does it properly print the URLs?

Comment: Yes, although there's a line break after the line

Comment: Is this code supposed to be part of the `ScreenShot` class? Or was that accidentally posted? I did not see that part initially.

Comment: It is part of it, actually it's the entire class, huge as it may be.

Comment: Oh ok. That changes everything. Is it not under a method? What you posted makes it look like it is 'free floating' underneath the class name definition (free floating isn't a technical definition just something I came up with to describe how it looked).

Comment: Yes, it's free floating (:p). I know java and c# but this is my first code in python so I haven't figured out basically anything yet. What changes should I make to make it work as a free floater?

Comment: First I would avoid that. Second are you expecting that to fire off when the class is instantiated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177817/discussion-between-adam-and-j-doe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a screenshot class is unnecessary for a simple task like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function

import os
from selenium import webdriver


def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    # With automatically closes files when they go out of scope
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        for url in f.readlines():
            driver.get(url)

            # os.path.join should make it platform agnostic
            # Also remove any '/' from the url and replace to avoid any file system save issues
            sn_name = os.path.join('Screenshots', url.strip().replace('/', '-') + '.png')
            print('Attempting to save:', sn_name)

            # '.save_screenshot' returns false if it fails so throw exception
            if not driver.save_screenshot(sn_name):
                raise Exception('Could not save screen shot: ' + sn_name)

    # Close browser
    driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It doesn't save the screenshots though. It compiles and opens the next in line but nothing is saved

Comment: Likely due to the newline character at the end of the string. See my updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work either. The strip does remove the newline though (print(line.strip())